# run python.py files

Tags: python, cmd.exe, terminal, atom-editor

Sorry if I sound a bit primitive. I literally starting learning python 5 minutes ago

When I try to run my program which I'm just using to test stuff

```
>>> print ('Hello World')
```

My text editor, Atom, just gives me

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

When I look it up all I get is people saying to use cmd to direct to the file

Even when I follow instructions it doesn't work

I get people saying to put C:Python36; in my path, which I have done

How can I check if I've downloaded python correctly and how do I direct to the right file in cmd and run the right file? English not programmer jabber. Actually, since I'm trying to learn programming jabber with English explanations would be helpful.

I have a folder on my Desktop called "Learning Code" and then a folder in there called "Learning Python" and then the file "learningPython.py"

Also, I know using the IDLE works

Thanks to whoever helps!!

Comment: Just to verify, the version of Python you download is indeed 3.6.x? The file path `C:\Python36` could be wrong if you have a different version installed.

Comment: Also the default installation path for Python 3.5+ is within one of the `C:\Program Files` folders.  In the root of C would not be the default location.  What you should do is know where you installed it then add that folder (the one that contains python.exe) to your system's PATH.  Your editor, Atom, then might need more configuration for debugging and such.  Visual Studio Code also has Python plugins, I use it, and it works well but *you have to read and follow instructions*.

Comment: `C:Python36` is missing a backslash ...